# Terraform forces replacement of 'aws_acm_certificate' with multiple 'subject_alternative_names'

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-acm

I'm trying to create a `aws_acm_certificate` with multiple `subject_alternative_names`

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  provider          = aws.acm
  domain_name       = local.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"
  subject_alternative_names = [local.domain_name, "www.${local.domain_name}"]
}
```

Running `apply` for the first time works as advertised. However, when I re-run `apply` with exactly the same vars terraform wants to re-create the cert with the following reason:

```
   ~ subject_alternative_names = [ # forces replacement
       + "xyz.com",
         "www.xyz.com",
     ]
```

It appears that `[local.domain_name, "www.${local.domain_name}"]` when compared with its current state comes up as different.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: BTW, I'm simply following the description in the terraform docs https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation and I'm using `Terraform v0.13.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `subject_alternative_names` shouldn't include the cert's own domain name.

If I change `subject_alternative_names` to `["www.${local.domain_name}"]` it seem to do the right thing. Not sure if this is a bug or enforcement of the proper way of using `subject_alternative_names` as I have seen many certs which include the own domain name in the `subject_alternative_names`.

If anybody has a better analysis I would love to hear it.

Comment: Thanks, this really saved me! I've created a github issue to fix the documentation you mentioned in your above comment and perhaps start a discussion about preventing this from happening at all since it seems likely it's a bug in the provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22734

Answer (score 0):

**subject_alternative_names**  seems to be the key. Kudos to max.ott

I was able to solve this using:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "vpn" {
  domain_name       =  "vpn.${var.domain_name}"
  certificate_authority_arn =aws_acmpca_certificate_authority.ca.arn
  subject_alternative_names = []
```